# Server 100% CPU At random times

Tags: central-processing-unit

I have a server with 12 Cores Intel XEON CPU, and 128GB RAM.
The server is dedicated, not a vps.

```
root@xx:~# lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
```

At random times the CPU is going to 100% to all cores and even in **htop** i don't see a process more than 4-5%

Check this image:

[http://prntscr.com/98sp3m](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEdOH.png)

Also is that a bit strange?
Look at

```
Tasks: 1071, 33 thr; 350 running
```

What is the 350 running? Because when my CPU is going to 100% that number is going to 350, but when the CPU is normal `it only says 2 Running`

Comment: Are you sure your measurement is for all CPUs? Assuming hyperthreading and 12 cores 4% or so would be maxing one thread out.

Comment: How random are these occurrences, and do they correlate to either network or IO activity?  See this question for a similar situation:  http://serverfault.com/questions/294505/high-cpu-usage-of-flush-process

Comment: I'm using a NGINX + PHP FPM. What i understand is that if i have for example 200 concurrect connecitons all ok. if i have 201 my CPU goes to maximum....

Comment: By the way, tried on CentOS 7.1 with exactly the same setup, same happened

Answer (score 1):

Run

```
ps -eo pcpu,pid,user,args | sort -k1 -r | head -10
```

This should tell you the top 10 apps/threads using your cpu resources.

Comment: It only shows CPU usage of 6.1-7% and only on the first 2 processes, while al lthe others are 0.... I really can't understand this

Comment: Can you paste the result in a pastebin so that we can see it?